# JQuery datepicker script stopped working suddently

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I've created a couple of jquery datepicker scripts (with the help from this site) to use together with Wordpress and Gravity Forms. The purpose is to restrict the user from picking certain weekdays.

Recently they all stopped working. Not sure if something has changed in recent wordpress upgrades. The script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(function ($) { $( "#input_2_5" ).datepicker({  minDate: 1, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',         beforeShowDay: function(d) {return ( 6==d.getDay()? [true,''] : [false,'']);} });     var days = [1, 4, 6];     $("#input_1_5").datepicker({         minDate: 1,         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',         beforeShowDay: function (d) {             return [$.inArray(d.getDay(), days) > -1, ''];
        }
    });
});
// ]]></script
```

The hastag #inpute_x_y refers to the form ID (x) and the form field (y).

In chrome debug i'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
```

In this line:

```
return [false, ''];
```

This script is being used in this page: ( http://vmtmadeira.com/catamaran-trips/desertas-islands/book-desertas-islands ). The field is the "Prefered Date*"

I'm using the same form in a website with an older version of wordpress (3.8.9) and it works flawlessly.

In all websites with the most recent version of wordpress, can't get it to work. Am i missing something. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. First, you must reduce your question to one or two specific areas. We cannot answer questions like: "my site is broken, please tell me what is wrong." Create an example, usually on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozunhv5z/) (add code to this link and press Update, then paste the URL). The example must demonstrate your problem and give us something to experiment with, to try to fix. We will do our best to help, but you must demonstrate the problem there. Good luck with your projects.

Comment: not sure it it's an issue, but check out on your second site how the datepicker function is partly converted to characters - square brackets for example http://prntscr.com/80ciey

Comment: Do you have any code you can post for us so we don't have to dig through your website? Maybe the html and js code which is involved in connecting the datepicker to that element?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i've rewritten the question, hopefully it's more straight forward. I'm really stuck here and don't know what to do.